# Custom InfoWindow Marker

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created an App which presents users with five options. They can select a city from these options and be directed to a new screen where they are shown a MapView of the city along with 3 markers. I want to create a customer InfoWindow when the user clicks on the marker. So I created a custom file called `infowindow.xml` in which I created the layout of the `InfoWindow`.

However, I am not too sure how to implement it in my `MapView`. I have provided all relevant code below:

any help or guidance will be appreciated.

`MainActivity.kt`

```
    import android.content.Intent
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.View
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.tanav.tanavsharma_mapd711_assignment3.models.Place
    import com.tanav.tanavsharma_mapd711_assignment3.models.UserMap
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            /* Setting the layout manager on the recycler view
             ************* layout manager is responsible for telling the
             ************* recycler view how to layout the views on the
             ************* screen
             * Set adapter on the recycler view
             */
    
            val cityMaps = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.cityMaps)
    
            val userMaps = generateSampleData()
            cityMaps.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            cityMaps.adapter = MapsAdapter(this, userMaps, object : MapsAdapter.OnClickListener{
                override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
                    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, DisplayMapActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("UserMap", userMaps[position])
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
    
            })
        }
    
        private fun generateSampleData(): List<UserMap> {
            return listOf(
                UserMap(
                    "Toronto",
                    listOf(
    
                        Place("CN Tower Cruise", "290 Bremner Blvd, Toronto, ON M5V 3L9", "416-900-0098", "Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.642905, -79.386900),
                        Place("Rail Way Cruise", "255 Bremner Blvd, Toronto, ON M5V 3M9", "416-900-0098","Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.640805, -79.385945),
                        Place("Pinkbery Cruise", "161 King St E, Toronto, ON M5C 1G9", "416-900-0098","Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.650050, -79.372404)
                    )
                ),
                UserMap("Mississauga",
                    listOf(
                        Place("Celebration Cruise", "300 City Centre Dr, Mississauga, ON L5B 3C1", "416-900-0098","Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.588070, -79.643000),
                        Place("Golden Cruise", "1177 Central Pkwy W Unit 59, Mississauga, ON L5C 4P3", "416-900-0098","Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.567164, -79.660391),
                        Place("Waterfall Cruise", "1180 Lakeshore Rd W, Mississauga, ON L5H 3L1", "416-900-0098","Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.519416, -79.603003)
                    )),
                UserMap("Oakville",
                    listOf(
                        Place("Lions Valley Cruise", "1227 Lions Valley Park Rd, Oakville, ON L6M 4L8", "416-900-0098","Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.459962, -79.748594),
                        Place("Lake Side Cruise", "2 Navy St, Oakville, ON L6J 2Y5", "416-900-0098","Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.441586,-79.666197),
                        Place("Coronation Cruise", "1426 Lakeshore Rd W, Oakville, ON L6L 1G2","416-900-0098","Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.409619, -79.692486),
                    )
                ),
                UserMap("Hamilton",
                    listOf(
                        Place("Heritage Cruise", "9280 Airport Rd, Mount Hope, ON L0R 1W0", "416-900-0098","Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.159565, -79.925317),
                        Place("Red Hill Cruise", "768 Mountain Brow Blvd, Hamilton, ON L8W 1R6", "416-900-0098","Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.200056, -79.819558),
                        Place("Spencer Cruise", "001 Harvest Rd, Dundas, ON L9H 4W2", "416-900-0098","Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.281500, -79.980189),
                    )
                ),
                UserMap("North York",
                    listOf(
                        Place("Fairview Cruise", "1800 Sheppard Ave E, Toronto, ON M2J 5A7", "416-900-0098","Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.777332, -79.344127),
                        Place("Pures Cruise", "1450 Midland Ave suite 200&300, Scarborough, ON M1P 4Z8","416-900-0098", "Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.751293, -79.265983),
                        Place("Leion Cruise", "430 Nugget Ave, Scarborough, ON M1S 5E1", "416-900-0098","Open 9:00 AM to 6:30 PM",43.798544, -79.243165),
                    )
                )
            )
        }

}
```

`DisplayMapActivity.kt`

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import com.tanav.tanavsharma_mapd711_assignment3.databinding.ActivityDisplayMapBinding
import com.tanav.tanavsharma_mapd711_assignment3.models.UserMap


class DisplayMapActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDisplayMapBinding
    private lateinit var userMap: UserMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityDisplayMapBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        userMap = intent.getSerializableExtra("UserMap") as UserMap

        supportActionBar?.title = userMap.title


        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId == R.id.standard){
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL)
        }else if(item.itemId == R.id.satellite){
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE)
        }else if(item.itemId == R.id.hybrid){
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID)
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        // Add a marker in the place of click and move the camera

        val boundsBuilder = LatLngBounds.Builder()
        for(place in userMap.places){
            val latlng = LatLng(place.latitude, place.longitude)
            boundsBuilder.include(latlng)
            mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(place.title).snippet(place.address).snippet(place.number).snippet(place.hours))
        }
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundsBuilder.build(), 1000, 1000, 0))
    }
```

`MapsAdapter.kt`

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.tanav.tanavsharma_mapd711_assignment3.models.UserMap

class MapsAdapter(val context: Context, val userMaps: List<UserMap>, val onClickListener: OnClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MapsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    interface OnClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val userMap = userMaps[position]
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onClickListener.onItemClick(position)
        }

        val textViewTitle = holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.text1)
        textViewTitle.text = userMap.title
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = userMaps.size

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

Here are the classes I have used, `Place.kt`

```
import java.io.Serializable

data class Place(val title: String, val address: String, val number: String, val hours: String, val latitude: Double, val longitude: Double ) : Serializable
```

& `UserMap.kt`

```
import java.io.Serializable

data class UserMap(val title: String, val places: List<Place>) : Serializable
```

`infowindow.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#99A2D6"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pictureStreet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
    
                />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hours"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

`CustomInfoWindowAdapter.kt`

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker

class CustomInfoWindowAdapter(private val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater): GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    var mlayoutInflater = layoutInflater
    var mWindow = (layoutInflater as Activity).layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow, null)

    private fun rendowWindowText(marker: Marker, view: View){

        val tvTitle = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title)
        val tvAddress = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.address)
        val tvNumber = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.number)
        val tvHours = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.hours)
        val ivPicture = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.pictureStreet)

        tvTitle.text = marker.title
        tvAddress.text = marker.address // red underline
        tvNumber.text = marker.number // red underline
        tvHours.text = marker.hours // red underline
        ivPicture.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.cntower) //red underline
    }

    override fun getInfoWindow(marker: Marker): View {
        //Inflate and return your infolayout
        rendowWindowText(marker, mWindow)
        return mWindow
    }

    override fun getInfoContents(marker: Marker): View {
        //Inflate and return your infolayout
        rendowWindowText(marker, mWindow)
        return mWindow
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a custom InfoViewAdapter class by extending GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter like

```
class CustomInfoWindowAdapter(private val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater):GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    override fun getInfoWindow(p0: Marker): View {
        //Inflate and return your infolayout
        return #YourInfoView
    }

    override fun getInfoContents(p0: Marker): View {
        //Inflate and return your infolayout
        return #YourInfoView
    }
}
```

Then in your onMapReady function assign your adapter to map

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(CustomInfoWindowAdapter(layoutInflater))
```

Thats it. It should show your info view on marker clicks

Comment: Don't forget to set your data on getInfoContents you cannot change infoWindows content later on.

Comment: I am gonna update my answer after implementing what you asked me to do. Please take a look and tell me what else is wrong. It cant seem to set my text views.

Comment: @TanavSharma You didn't set your adapter to your map in your onMapReady.

Comment: I did add it in my code but forgot to update it here. However, the error I am getting is in my `CustomInfoWindowAdapter` class. `marker.address` , `marker.number` etc... show up red. Do you know why?

Comment: @TanavSharma Marker class doesn't have those properties. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerOptions-Properties

Comment: You can tag your Place object to a marker and use it from there. In your  rendowWindowText func. your can use as (marker.tag as Place).address etc.

Comment: Thank you!, finally!!

Comment: @TanavSharma Can you mark this as an answer? Appreciate it.